# Pagination not working in asp:DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, pagination

Problem:

When I attempt to go to page 2 or any other subsequent page of the data grid, it does nothing but refresh the page.

Markup:

```
<!--Main DataGrid-->
<asp:DataGrid
        ID="dgTasks"
        runat="server"
        PageSize="40"
        AllowPaging="true"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        ForeColor="#333333"
        GridLines="Both"
        Font-Size="Small"
        AllowSorting="true"
        OnItemDataBound="Item_DataBound" >
        <HeaderStyle
            BackColor="#990000"
            Font-Bold="True"
            ForeColor="White"
            HorizontalAlign="Center"
            Font-Size="Small"/> 
        <Columns>
            ...
        </Columns>
        <SelectedItemStyle
            BackColor="#FFCC66"
            Font-Bold="True"
            ForeColor="Navy" />
        <PagerStyle
            BackColor="#CCCCCC"
            ForeColor="#333333"
            HorizontalAlign="Right"
            Mode="NumericPages" /> 
        <AlternatingItemStyle
            BackColor="White" /> 
        <ItemStyle
            BackColor="#FFFBD6"
            ForeColor="#333333" /> 
        <FooterStyle
            BackColor="#990000"
            Font-Bold="True"
            ForeColor="White" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Code Behind:

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsPostBack Then
        'DoNothing'
    Else
        BindData("")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BindData(ByVal strDisplayCompleted As String, ByVal strSort As String)
    Dim taskDataSet As TaskDataSet = New TaskDataSet()
    Dim dt As DataTable = taskDataSet.GetData("N").Tables(0)
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If dr.Item(2).ToString().StartsWith("Vacancy") Then
            dr.Delete()
        End If
    Next

    If strSort.Length > 0 Then
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = strSort
    End If
    dgTasks.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
    dgTasks.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub BindData(ByVal strSort As String)
    BindData("N", strSort)
End Sub
```

Now, I'm not even close to sure why the pagination is not working.  I have `AllowPaging` equal to true, I'm not re-binding the data on PostBack, so I'm confused.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear you are binding the datagrid to a control like ObjectDataSource, EntityDataSource which would automatically take care of the paging for you.

You would need to handle Paging event from the gridview and then reset the page index yourself

i.e.

gridview.PageIndex = e.newPageIndex

(I am not at machine with IDE so cant confirm this is syntactically correct right now)